# terraform templatefile for aws policies list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have an example of this below from my main.tf.
For some reason it forces double quotes on the template variables to wrap around on my template file while examples from other sources using below without quote wrap:

```
%{ for i in split(",",mylist) ~}
Here's a value: ${i}
%{ endfor }
```

My syntax shows no error on the file but it will error out when running it
"%{ for addr in split(",",source_vpcs) ~} ${addr} %{ endfor ~}"

i am getting this error:
Invalid function
argument; Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required..

how can I correctly make use of the list?
source_vpcs = ["vpc1212","vpc21"]

```
#i am trying to pass this from the main.tf to pass into aws_vpc_endpoint resource and into its policy attribute.

    policy = templatefile("../templates/access_polices.tmpl", 
                   {
                     s3env = "dev"
                     account_num = "8888888"
                     source_vpcs = local.source_vpcs
                   }
               )
```

here is an the tmpl file
####new content###

```
${jsonencode(
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xx",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "*"
              ],
            "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
              "aws:SourceVpc": "${source_vpcs}",
              "s3:ResourceAccount": "${account_number}"
              }
        }
        },
        
    ]
}
)}
```

This is my a sample output that I want to achieve

```
"Condition": {
  "StringNotEquals": {
    "aws:SourceVpc": 
    [
      "vpc-888888888f",
      "vpc-999999999f"

    ]
    ,
    "s3:ResourceAccount":
    [
        888888888
     ]
  }
```

Comment: Terraform is releasing new versions every two seconds :D, if you can provide terraform version you use can help others to answer your question.

Comment: I also tried jsonencode function ${jsonencode(policy)} on the tmpl file and i was able to do a terraform plan as if it looked good but when i applied it it doesn't see it as a valid policy. I had crossed check if the policy is correct.

Comment: Hi Vidura, i am using Terraform v0.13.4

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `source_vpcs` in as a list, then trying to split a list on `","`.

Since you're already passing in a list, you don't need to do the split; it's already in different elements. So, just get rid of the `split` and try this:

```
"%{ for addr in source_vpcs ~} ${addr} %{ endfor ~}"
```

**EDIT:**
This minimal example works fine for me, no errors.

**template.txt**

```
%{ for v in mylist ~}
Here's a value: ${v}
%{ endfor }
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "local_file" "template_test" {
  content     = templatefile("./template.txt", {
    mylist = [
      "value 1",
      "value 2"
    ]
  })
  filename = "./output.txt"
}
```

**output.txt**

```
Here's a value: value 1
Here's a value: value 2
```

**EDIT 2:**
I don't know what you're trying to do with this JSON, and you should really consider using the [aws_iam_policy_document data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) for IAM policies like this, but here's how you can create the JSON string:

```
locals {
  source_vpcs = [
      "vpc-888888888f",
      "vpc-999999999f"
  ]
  account_number = 888888888

  jsonstring = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
        {
            Sid = "xx",
            Effect = "Deny",
            Action = [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            Resource = [
                "*"
            ],
            Condition = {
                StringNotEquals = {
                  "aws:SourceVpc" = local.source_vpcs,
                  "s3:ResourceAccount" = local.account_number
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  })
}

output "jsonstring" {
  value = local.jsonstring
}
```

Now you can use `local.jsonstring` anywhere you want to use that string (like in an IAM policy). If you *really* want to output it to a file, you can add:

```
resource "local_file" "jsonfile" {
  content     = local.jsonstring
  filename = "./policy.json"
}
```

And now `policy.json` will have your JSON content.

**EDIT 3:**
Try this:

`templatedir/policytemplate.json`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xx",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "*"
              ],
            "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
              "aws:SourceVpc": ${jsonencode(vpc_ids)},
              "s3:ResourceAccount": "${account_number}"
              }
        }
        },
        
    ]
}
```

`main.tf`

```
locals {
  jsonpolicy = templatefile("./templatedir/policytemplate.json", {
    vpc_ids = [
      "vpc_1",
      "vpc_2"
    ]
    account_number = 888888
  })
}

output "jsonpolicy" {
  value = local.jsonpolicy
}
```

Comment: I have done first before splitting. It didn't work.

Comment: Check my edited answer for a minimal working example. That as-is to ensure it works, then add in the other components of your template to see where the issue is cropping up.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I was able to replicate your step when it comes to outputting a text file but where my problem is with working with json file.

let me edit my main question (where i say "new content" to provide an example template file i want achieved. 
I using this templatefile function so i can place that on the policy attribute of  aws_vpc_endpoint resource

Comment: What are you doing with this output JSON file? If you're reading it back into Terraform to create an IAM policy with it, there are much easier ways to accomplish this without having to use an external file at all.

Comment: I see. I never tried that. Reason why I am not using aws_iam_policy_document data source  nor that way you just updated because I have about 16 endpoints and each one have a different policy and some may have additional statements. So what i had already done was placed each json policy into a file in a folder and tried to do a templatefile out of each different file.

Comment: What are you actually doing with the resulting JSON though? Are you using it in a resource?

Comment: I pass the policy variable into the aws_vpc_endpoint resource.

Because of so many different files, i just instead placed the individual policies inside a folder and using file(policy,json) instead of setting these variables inside json file.